# Neutron configuration error : Failed to retrieve extensions list from Network API

Tags: openstack-neutron

I am going with minimal install of openstack queens, with 1 controller with all openstack services and 3 compute nodes, i have installed keystone, glance and nova they are working well, i configured neutron service with provider network configuration as per the installation guide , when i try to verify neutron service by using the command " openstack extension list --network" i got an error showing unable to retrieve extensions from nova api, when i went through the logs i found that the auth_url is suitable for the plugin
When I checked the logs it shows

**Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin**

The log file can be found in the below link
**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BGegFJEqt3nuYH4FpX4p7l2SXAt95u17/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: Please add an example of what you tried to do, see the instructions on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will help us to answer your question faster and better.

Comment: I am going with minimal install of openstack queens, with 1 controller with all openstack services and 3 compute nodes, i have installed keystone, glance and nova they are working well, i configured neutron service with provider network configuration as per the installation guide , when i try to verify neutron service by using the command " openstack extension list --network" i got an error showing unable to retrieve extensions from nova api, when i went through the logs i found that the auth_url  is suitable for the plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can try in **[keystone_authtoken]** section in **neutron.conf** file to :

- remove `auth_url = http://controller:35357`
- replace `auth_uri = ...` by `auth_url = ...`